# Which libc function reserves a port number so the OS won't allow other processes to use it?

Tags: networking, rust, libc

I am writing a my first low-level networking application (a simple VPN) in rust and need to modify both the IP source address and TCP/UDP source port for each packet. Therefore I need to use raw sockets and don't get the added convenience of the OS reserving port numbers.

How can I tell the OS to reserve a range of ports so that it won't assign them to other applications and create a conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell the OS to "reserve" a port apart from associating it with a socket, i.e. create a socket and [bind](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) to the address and port.

Apart from that VPN are typically implemented by having a virtual network adapter like [TUN/TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) with its own IP address and with appropriate routing to define which traffic should be passed through the VPN. No address or port rewriting needs to be done in this case.

Comment: From my understanding, raw sockets don't have any way to assign a port. You are responsible for providing the raw packet, which would include the source port in the transport header. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Oh, rewriting is handled by the OS. I think I'm missing a few layers of the stack in my mental model. The way I was trying to do it would require direct access to the network device's memory segment.